# При создании потоков программа перестает что-либо выводить

Tags: java, многопоточность

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("class\\s+(?<class>\\w+)(\\s+extends\\s+(?<extends>\\w+))?(\\s+implements\\s+(?<implements>\\w+))?");
    private static Map<String, Set<String>> classMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


public static synchronized void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File src = new File("E:\\Загрузки\\2_laba\\2 лаба");
    listFilesForFolder(src);
    classMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " : " + value));
}

public static synchronized void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) throws IOException {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    parseFile(fileEntry);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start() ;
        }
    }
}

private static synchronized void parseFile(File file) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        reader.lines().forEach(line -> {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String s = matcher.group();
                addToMap(s);
            }
        });
    }

}

private static synchronized void addToMap(String s) {
    String[] split = s.split("(\\sextends\\s|\\simplements\\s|\\s\\{|,\\s)");
    String child = split[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
        /*String parent = split[i];
        if (!classMap.containsKey(split[i])) {
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
            set.add(child);
            classMap.put(parent, set);
        } else {
            classMap.get(parent).add(child);
        }*/
        String parent = split[i];
        Set<String> orDefault = classMap.getOrDefault(parent, new HashSet<>());
        orDefault.add(child);
        classMap.put(parent, orDefault);
    }
}      }
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, почему программа перестала выводить результат работы, после создания потоков. И как исправить?
Результат должен быть такой https://clip2net.com/s/44uzErl

Comment: На вскидку: у вас  `listFilesForFolder(src);` выполняется медленнее чем `classMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " : " + value));` То есть т.к. у вас потоки - то ещё ничего не заполеннно, а вы уже всё вывели. Ради эксперемента поставьте задержку на пару сек между ними(методами)

Answer (score 2):

Надо собирать ссылки на все потоки, что ты запустил, ждать их завершения (`thread.join()`) и только потом печатать.

Но лучше всего использовать пул потоков, потому что в том виде, как сделано у тебя, если на вход подать папку с тысячами файлов, то приложение просто упадёт с `OutOfMemoryError`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File src = new File("E:\\Загрузки\\2_laba\\2 лаба");
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    listFilesForFolder(src, executor);
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);  
    classMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " : " + value));
}

public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder, ExecutorService executor) throws IOException {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry, executor);
        } else {
            executor.execute(() -> {
                try {
                    parseFile(fileEntry);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

И, кстати, ни один из модификаторов `synchronized` в твоей программе не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо большое, программа стала работать, но теперь у меня появилась новая проблема, каждый запуск программы, она выводит разный результат, я так понял это возникло Race condition?

Comment: @newcodder в чём "разность" заключается?

Comment: Программа выводит наследование классов, вот правильный вывод. http://c2n.me/44NyXRQ
А вот еще вариант вывода этого же кода http://c2n.me/44Nz2n3

Comment: Да, вместо `getOrDefault + pur` надо использовать `compiteIfAbsent`.