# Прошу помощи в понимании интерфейса Future<>

Tags: java, многопоточность

В университете дали задание, написать поискового робота, с помощью ExecutorServise, а доступ к единому индексу должен получаться с помощью Future<>. И я не могу никак додумать, что я должен сделать чтобы выполнить данное условие[image: Вот скриншот задания]

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Path dir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("src\\package\\");
        Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.java")) {
            for (Path path : stream) {
                CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                executor.execute(() -> {
                    try {
                        synchronized (result) {
                            countDownLatch.countDown();
                            String string = Files.lines(Paths.get("src\\package\\" + path.getFileName()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                                    .collect(Collectors.joining());
                            String regex = "class\\s+(?<class>\\w+)\\s+(extends\\s+(?<extends>\\w+))?";
                            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
                            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
                            if (matcher.find()) {
                                String child = matcher.group("class");
                                String parent = matcher.group("extends");
                                List<String> children = result.getOrDefault(parent, new ArrayList<>());
                                children.addAll(Collections.singleton(child));
                                result.put(parent, children);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                countDownLatch.await();
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));

    }
}
```

Вот собственно, сам код, джаве только учусь, поэтому не судите строго. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Этот код уже разбирали месяц назад, разве нет? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1043805/При-создании-потоков-программа-перестает-что-либо-выводить/1044031

Comment: Только за прошедший месяц ты его хуже сделал. `CountDownLatch` не нужен. `synchronized (result` делает твой код однопоточным. В старом варианте был синхронизованный Map и это было правильно.

Comment: Ещё старый вариант корректно рекурсивные папки обрабатывал

Comment: Ещё тебе говорили заменить `getOrDefault + put` на `computeIfAbsent`, но ты этого так и не сделал.

Comment: "Вот собственно, сам код, джаве только учусь, поэтому не судите строго" чего-то не заметно. Как использовал конструкции не пытаясь их понять, так и используешь.

Answer (score 2):

`ExecutorService` помимо запуска `Runnable` способен исполнять `Callable`, которые имеют возможность возвращать результат работы потока. Этот результат оборорачивается в экземпляр интерфейса `Future`, который потом можно будет опросить на предмет готовности результата, получения результата и т.д. Обычно, при запуске нескольких `Callable`, экземпляры `Future` получают после вызова у инстанса `ExecutorService` метода `submit()` либо `invokeAll()` с последующим сохранением их в списке, анализом состояния и получением данных. Примерно вот так может выглядеть ваш код (синхронизация внутри потоков для обновления `Map` уже не нужна ввиду того, что результаты кладутся в мапу уже после выполнения потоков):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path dir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("src\\package\\");
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
    ArrayList<Future<Map.Entry<String, String>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.java")) {
        for (Path path : stream) {

            Future<Map.Entry<String, String>> future = executor.submit(() -> {
                Map.Entry<String, String> result = null;
                try {
                    String string = Files.lines(Paths.get("src\\package\\" + path.getFileName()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                            .collect(Collectors.joining());
                    String regex = "class\\s+(?<class>\\w+)\\s+(extends\\s+(?<extends>\\w+))?";
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
                    if (matcher.find()) {
                        String child = matcher.group("class");
                        String parent = matcher.group("extends");
                        result = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(parent, child);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            });
            futures.add(future);
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Future<Map.Entry<String, String>> future : futures) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry = future.get();
        result.merge(entry.getKey(), Collections.singletonList(entry.getValue()), (oldL, newL) -> {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(oldL);
            list.addAll(newL);
            return list;
        });
    }
    result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
}
```